# Why doesn't alwaysOnTop: true noi electron work when another app is fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, electron, always-on-top

Electron apps set to `always On Top: true`, do not stay on top when other apps are in F11 mode or fullscreen

I was hoping it would stay on top, it doesn't matter if other apps are fullscreen, I've researched a lot and maybe I don't really have a solution but I'd like to make sure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have two or more apps that have requested to be "always on top" at the same time.

Windows can't actually make them both on top at the same time, that doesn't make sense. One of them has to be on top of the other.

Maybe you want to tell Windows that your app is more important than other apps and your app should always win. But the authors of the other apps also want their apps to always win. So it wouldn't make sense for Microsoft to give you that option, unless they did something really awful like selling it to the highest bidder so the most expensive app is always on top. I don't want that!

Comment: Really, the worst thing is that I managed, not pretty, but I managed...